# How to integrate wooCommerce into non-wordpress site

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm totally new to this, how should I start to integrate woocommerce into my localhost for testing on a non-wordpress site?
I check online people have mention that to use sub-directory, I have tried it but I am stuck at the logging in with database part.

Please advise on how should I do it. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the sub-directory you’ll need to install WordPress first and then add the WooCommerce plugin to it.
Then, you can add a “SHOP” link to your existing site navigation menu, and this will link to your WordPress/WooCommerce website.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: Hi @Aftab Husain thanks for your advise i have managed to created the wordpress inside my sub-directory. May i ask you, what should i do if i want my existing site to be able to connect to other woocommerce store by using the url ?

Comment: Means you want to add the link of the created woo-commerce store to your existing wordpress site. Right?

Comment: Hi thanks for your time to answer, i have managed to connect it using the generated api key.

Comment: ok, Thank you. Please mark correct to my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install WordPress as a sub-directory of your non WordPress site and then integrate woo-commerce plugin in it , otherwise it will not work.